# Images are not properly displaying on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have images in a UIScrollView, but the images are not displaying properly. The problem is that images are not at the same size. I want every image with the same size and height.

```
for (UIView *v in [_scrollView subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}

//CGRect workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;
CGRect workingFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 134);
workingFrame.origin.x =0;

NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];


for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {

    UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [images addObject:image];

    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    imageview.frame = workingFrame;

    [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];
    [imageview release];

    workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
}

self.chosenImages = images;
NSLog(@"values=%@",_chosenImages);

[_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` you will have the image with the maximum size of the UIImageView, but often smaller. If you want it to fill and have all the same size and keep aspect you have to set:

```
[imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageview setClipsToBounds:YES];
```